# How can I delete half of the sequentially numbered files in a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, script

A directory has files with names ending 001 to 100.
How can you delete 2,4,6,8...100.
And can that be written as a script. As soon as the directory becomes week old, this has to run. And after a month again. The goal is to delete half of the not-recent data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a bash for loop with a step (if its bash v4)

so it would be

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

cd /path/to/directory/

for i in `ls *{0..100..2}`
do 
    rm $i
done
```

this can be put in your crontab to run every week/month

00 11 1 * * /path/to/script.sh    will run it on the first day of the month at 11am

00 11 * * 1 /path/to/script.sh    will run it every monday

Comment: I like the idea. What if I want to sort the files according to name. And for the first week, and then after a month, and then at quarter, and then a year,       : delete every other file in the sorted list.

Comment: Thats good.
What if the names are not fixed, but are sorted alphabetically, and the directory has to go through this loop after a week && a month && quarter && year. So if I have 1024 files at first, after a week I'll have 512, then 256, then 128, and after a year 64. So that the recent data stays in high resolution, while old data is not totally removed.

Comment: to be honest that would probably be better being asked as a separate question

Answer (score 1):

Something like this *should* work (can't test right now so **test on duplicate data first**) -

```
 find /path/to/directory -type f -name '*[02468].jpg' -delete
```

or with `rm` -

```
 find /path/to/directory -type f -name '*[02468].jpg' -exec rm {} +
```